# Trying to use Minimum Spanning Tree example from the book but It doesn't work with large data

Tags: c++, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Note: This is not my code

I am trying to use the data structures with C++ textbook's Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm but as you can see I made a edges[] array of edges and commented out the old edges[] array but It looks like it doesn't work for larger amount of edge or something. (I am just using chars as ints by the way)

Does anyone know why? I didn't change a lot, I just changed the edges array.
It compiles just fine but If you run it you will see that it won't work with my data but It will with the original data.

The arrays are right over the main (last thing)

Also if you don't want to open up your ide, here is my code on an online IDE: http://goo.gl/35KMcK

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MSTEdge
{
    char src;
    char dest;
    int weight;
public:
    MSTEdge(char s = 0, char d = 0, int w = 0) : src(s), dest(d), weight(w) { }
    char& getSrc() { return src; }
    char& getDest() { return dest; }
    int& getWeight() { return weight; }
    int& get() { return getWeight(); }
};

// undirected and weighted graph
class Graph
{
    int V, E;
    MSTEdge* edge;
    int icount;
public:
    Graph(int v, int e) : V(v), E(e), icount(0)
    {
        edge = new MSTEdge[e];
    }
    int& getVertexAmount() { return V; }
    int& getEdgeAmount() { return E; }
    MSTEdge*& getEdges() { return edge; }
    MSTEdge& operator [](int x) { return edge[x]; }
    void insert(MSTEdge& e)
    {
        edge[icount++] = e;
    }
};

// subset for union-find
class subset
{
    int parent;
    int rank;
public:
    subset(int p = 0, int r = 0) : parent(p), rank(r) {}
    int& getTheParent() { return parent; }
    int& getTheRank() { return rank; }
};

// find set of an element i
int find(subset* subsets, int i)
{
    // find root and make root as parent of i (path compression)
    if (subsets[i].getTheParent() != i)
        subsets[i].getTheParent() = find(subsets, subsets[i].getTheParent());

    return subsets[i].getTheParent();
}

// union of two sets of x and y
void Union(subset* subsets, int x, int y)
{
    int x_root = find(subsets, x);
    int yroot = find(subsets, y);

    // Attach smaller rank tree under root of high rank tree
    // (Union by Rank)
    if (subsets[x_root].getTheRank() < subsets[yroot].getTheRank())
        subsets[x_root].getTheParent() = yroot;
    else if (subsets[x_root].getTheRank() > subsets[yroot].getTheRank())
        subsets[yroot].getTheParent() = x_root;

    // If ranks are same, then make one as root and increment its rank by one
    else
    {
        subsets[yroot].getTheParent() = x_root;
        subsets[x_root].getTheRank()++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void partition_array(T* arr, int& i, int& j, T pivot)
{
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (arr[i].get() < pivot.get())
            i++;
        while (arr[j].get() > pivot.get())
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            T tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };
}

template <typename T>
void quickSort_array(T* arr, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    T pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    // partition 
    partition_array(arr, i, j, pivot);

    // recursion 
    if (left < j)
        quickSort_array(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort_array(arr, i, right);
}

// The main function to construct MST
void MST(Graph& graph)
{
    int V = graph.getVertexAmount();
    MSTEdge* result = new MSTEdge[V];  // Tnis will store the resultant MST
    int e = 0;  // An index variable, used for result[]
    int i = 0;  // An index variable, used for sorted edges

    quickSort_array(graph.getEdges(), 0, graph.getEdgeAmount());

    // Allocate memory for creating V ssubsets
    subset* subsets = new subset[V];

    // Create V subsets with single elements
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v)
    {
        subsets[v].getTheParent() = v;
        subsets[v].getTheRank() = 0;
    }

    // Number of edges to be taken is equal to V-1
    while (e < V - 1)
    {
        // Step 2: Pick the smallest edge. And increment the index
        // for next iteration
        MSTEdge next_edge = graph[i++];

        int x = find(subsets, next_edge.getSrc());
        int y = find(subsets, next_edge.getDest());

        // If including this edge does't cause cycle, include it
        // in result and increment the index of result for next edge
        if (x != y)
        {
            result[e++] = next_edge;
            Union(subsets, x, y);
        }
        // Else discard the next_edge
    }

    // print the contents of result[] to display the built MST
    cout << "Following are the edges in the constructed MST\n";
    for (i = 0; i < e; ++i)
        cout
        << result[i].getSrc()
        << " -- "
        << result[i].getDest()
        << " == "
        << result[i].getWeight()
        << endl;
    return;
}

/* weighted graph
10
0-------- 1
|  \     |
6|   5\  |15
|      \ |
2 --------3
4
*/


//MSTEdge edges[] =  //THIS WORKS
//{
//  MSTEdge(0,1,10),
//  MSTEdge(0,2,6),
//  MSTEdge(0,3,5),
//  MSTEdge(1,3,15),
//  MSTEdge(2,3,4)
//};

MSTEdge edges[] =    // CAUSES PROBLEMS
{
    MSTEdge('A','B',5),
    MSTEdge('A','C',1),
    MSTEdge('B','C',10),
    MSTEdge('B','E',13),
    MSTEdge('C','D',5),
    MSTEdge('D','E',15),
    MSTEdge('D','F',10),
    MSTEdge('E','F',17)
};


// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int count = sizeof(edges) / sizeof(MSTEdge);
    int V = count - 1;  // Number of vertices in graph
    Graph graph(V, count);
    for (int e = 0; e < count; e++)
        graph.insert(edges[e]);
    MST(graph);
    return 1;
}

// Following are the edges in the constructed MST
// 2 -- 3 == 4
// 0 -- 3 == 5
// 0 -- 1 == 10
```

Comment: _"It compiles just fine ..."_ [Your code doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/wf2PrF)!

Comment: Oh I see. That was before my edit where both arrays were commented out. Mine and the book's. I edited it now so that only the books is commented out. The arrays I'm talking about are over the main.

Answer (score 1):

The `subsets` array is initialized using this code:

```
// Create V subsets with single elements
for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v)
{
    subsets[v].getTheParent() = v;
    subsets[v].getTheRank() = 0;
}
```

This gives you subsets having `parent` values from 0 to V-1

The code then tries to find those subsets using this line

```
int x = find(subsets, next_edge.getSrc());
```

But your edges have source and destination set to 'A', 'B', 'C' etc. So it will never be able to find anything in `subsets`. It is probably accessing items outside the array bounds of `subsets` and causing undefined behaviour.

To fix it, either change your `edges` array to use 0, 1, 2, as the node IDs (probably easiest), or change the `subsets` initialize code to set the parents to 'A', 'B', 'C' etc. Note: there may be more places that assume the node IDs start from 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So if I really want to use letters, I have to offset the subset initializer to 65 since A starts at 65 right? so it would start at v=65 and end at V+65

Comment: Something like that. As I said, you will need to check if there is anything else that assumes the nodes start at 0.